# Can a Linux Kernel defconfig file be sorted?

Tags: linux-kernel, config

So I use defconfig files to keep the kernel settings/configuration for an embedded project.
Whenever I do changes to the actual config through means like `make menuconfig` and then do a  `make savedefconfig` afterwards the resulting defconfig file looks completely different to the preexisting one. The order of contained config options seems random at least or following some order not obviously understandable.

Problem about this for me the defconfig files are not diff-able anymore.
To work around this I want to sort the defconfig file before checking it in.
This way I can perfectly track any changes using any diff-tool.

Question is:
Is there any inherent order necessary in defconfig files for the linux kernel. Will this mess with the kernel build system in any way?

Comment: You can sort it. No problem. The file will just set the default values before the configuration is run, so order do not matter.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You want to put that as the answer?